# SFML Open multiple windows: Won't let me open more than two windows at a time

Tags: c++, sfml

Ok so I have a program that has a void that opens a new window then draws a image on that window every time I call the void. It will let me open a second window but won't let me open it again till I close the second window. I think I am thinking about it wrong if I am can someone give me a better way to do it. Here's my code I don't think its 100% necessary but idk.

My goal is to get it to allow me to open multiple windows doing their own thing on the screen. I am trying to open a new window by calling the `DrawKey` void.

It is opening a window when I press a key the first time but it is limiting me to the main window and one key window. I want to be able to have as many key windows open as I feel the need for.

```cpp
class MakeKey
{
public:
    typedef struct KeySprite {
        sf::Image Img;
        sf::Texture Tex;
        sf::Sprite Sprite;
    }Key;
    static bool setTransparency(HWND hwnd, unsigned char alpha) { ... }
    static bool setShape(HWND hwnd, const sf::Image& image) { ... }
    static sf::Vector2i RandSpawn(sf::Image image) { ... }
    static void MakeTopWindow(HWND hwnd) { ... }

    static void DrawKey(string key)
    {
        const unsigned char opacity = 1000;
        Key Key;
        Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
        sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(Key.Img.getSize().x, Key.Img.getSize().y, 32), "Key", sf::Style::None);
        setTransparency(window.getSystemHandle(), opacity);
        if (key == "A")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/A.png");
        else if (key == "D")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/D.png");
        else if (key == "E")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/E.png");
        else if (key == "Q")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/Q.png");
        else if (key == "S")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/S.png");
        else if (key == "W")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/W.png");
        else if (key == "X")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/X.png");
        else if (key == "Z")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/Z.png");
        else if (key == "Esc")
            Key.Img.loadFromFile("Assets/Images/esc.png");
        setShape(window.getSystemHandle(), Key.Img);
        Key.Tex.loadFromImage(Key.Img);
        Key.Sprite.setTexture(Key.Tex);
        window.setPosition(MakeKey::RandSpawn(Key.Img));
        while (window.isOpen())
        {
            MakeTopWindow(window.getSystemHandle());
            window.clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
            window.draw(Key.Sprite);
            window.display();
        }
    }

};
```

Main

```cpp
int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(100, 100, 32), "Main Window", sf::Style::None);
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            MakeKey::MakeTopWindow(window.getSystemHandle());
            if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed) {
                if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("A");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::D)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("D");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::E)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("E");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Q)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("Q");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::S)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("S");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::W)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("W");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::X)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("X");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Z)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("Z");
                else if (event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::Escape)
                    MakeKey::DrawKey("Esc");
            }
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }
        MakeKey::MakeTopWindow(window.getSystemHandle());
        window.clear(sf::Color::Transparent);
        window.display();
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There is no error just no doing quite what I want and I want help figuring out how to make it do what I want.

Comment: Thanks for the code. Code is almost always necessary. Even if it turns out that the code is wrong (and if it is right why are you asking a question here?) it might only need a small tweak. If it's wrong enough to need rewrite, the code provides a good baseline for people to use to write an answer that gets you back on the right path. Even better, the code provides a concrete link from problem to solution that will help future askers understand the full context of the question and answers, and providing answers to many programmers is the real reason Stack Overflow exists.

Comment: What do you mean *multiple windows or multithreading*? Maybe you should include what the code does and what you want it to do.

Comment: Someone?? Help please.

Comment: You have 2 "main loops". The `while (window.isOpen())` loop in `DrawKey` should not be there. Please add your windows to a container, and use that to check your windows.

Comment: ok thank you for your response. That sounds good. Would I do that with a vector of windows and use .pushback a new window or is there a better way.